# How to delete multiple Ext components at the same time.-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to remove multiple elements from an array using EXTjs using id of the comp.

```
Ext.getCmp('id1').destroy();
```

However how can I do if i have to delete multiple comp ids, like:

```
Ext.getCmp('id3').destroy()
Ext.getCmp('id4').destroy()
Ext.getCmp('id5').destroy()
```

Any ideas?thx

Comment: Using Id's is bad practise, you have to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var cmpIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];

   Ext.Array.each(cmpIds, function(cmpId){
       var cmp = Ext.getCmp(cmpId);
       if (cmp){
          cmp.destroy();
       }
    });
```

Comment: Ext.Array throws undefined, any clue why?

Comment: Because you didn't state what version you're using.

Comment: version:EXT-3.4-I used Ext.each() and it worked fine!